# Can a transaction have preemption scenario and OOS scenario both?

Tags: guidewire

Can a transaction have preemption scenario and OOS scenario both ?

This was asked to me in an interview.

My thought is that it can be because preemption is dependent on Policy Period and OOS is dependent on Effective Date.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but the two scenarios express themselves in very different ways.

An Out of Sequence (OOS) scenario happens when a change is dated before some other change to the policy that has already been issued.  Therefore a midterm change will be detected as OOS as part of starting the transaction, and the user will be warned of this case.  A midterm change is OOS if any effdated object on the policy has a slice (ie an effectiveDate) after the effective date of the change in question.

A pre-emption occurs when a midterm change is started, but before being issued an entirely separate change is issued.  The pre-empted change is flagged for correction and can't be issued until the pre-emption is handled.  Pre-emption is a data condition that has nothing directly to do with the dates on the policy or the pending change, although how it is handled depends on the dates.

Note that a pre-emption can create an OOS scenario depending on the date ordering of the effective dates.

This is all documented in the product documentation here (requires login).
https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202310/app/app/pc/topics/c_bu2695159.html?hl=preemptions,preemption

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible for the same job to be out of sequence and pre-empted by another job by virtue of their effective dates. Martin's answer is a great explanation for both scenarios. I can make it easier to comprehend through an example:

> **Job 1**: Submission with `Effective Date = 1st March` gets bound.
>
> **Job 2**: A policy change that increases coverage limits is done with `Effective Date = 1st April` and quoted, but not bound yet.
>
> **Job 3**: Another policy change is started with `Effective Date = 15th March`.
>
> **Job 2** is bound.

Job 3 will be preempted by Job 2 when Job 2 gets bound. Job 3 is also out of sequence since the effective date is before the effective date of Job 2's existing bound period.

Now let's say that when Job 2 is bound, PolicyCenter will display a link saying *"Your policy change preempted policy change 3"*. When the user navigates to job 3 by clicking the link, they will be shown two messages stating that **job 3 is preempted as well as out-of-sequence**. They get an option to handle the preemption by either applying all changes from the bound job (effectively refreshing the current period with the changes from the latest bound one) or by withdrawing the job.

Comment: Well Job 3 can't really be effective as it predates the Submission. Also it will not be an OOS to Job 2 as it is based on the graph from Submission which has nothing to do with Job 2 as this one isn't bound.

Comment: Sorry, I intended to provide an effective date between Job 1 & 2, corrected that now. Also, I think Job 3 becomes out of sequence as soon as Job 2 is bound as there are future transactions on 1st April.

Comment: Yeah I saw your correction - that's cool. However Job 3 will not be OOS as it was bound in-sequence at the time of being bound. And if the Job 2 is effective after Job 3 all will be in-sequence assuming Job 2 will have the pre-emption resolved before being bound

Comment: The idea behind the example was to generate an Out-of-Sequence (OOS) and preempted job in the easiest possible way. In my example, Job 3 will be both OOS and preempted even while it is in Draft status. PolicyCenter can consider a draft job as OOS, so I'm not sure why a job must be bound to qualify as an OOS job. I even verified this scenario by replicating it on PC, and after Job 2 gets bound, PC will show two messages about Job 3 being OOS and preempted, which I believe was the intent of the question.

Comment: yes, now your scenario is correctly presenting the twists - thanks!